# Dropdown дублирование кода, как упростить?

Tags: jquery, click, this, dropdown, each

На сайте несколько выпадающих списоков. Кликаешь по select__title, появляется select__dropdown. В каждом select__dropdown есть  li, при клике на li к this li добавляется active, а у всех других в данном select__dropdown, active убирается. Соответственно активность в каждом select__dropdown независима от других. Код уже написан, но используя дублирование, с чем я не могу смириться. То есть представленный jQuery код ctrl+c + ctrl+v но с разными переменными. Как можно использовав минимум кода это переписать, чтобы избежать дублирования.
Создавал массив c .filter__select_age li, .filter__select_country li... Потом этот масив перебирал с помощью each() и вместо переменной на которую повешено событие ставил this, тоже самое с span, но безуспешно. Про $(this).not(this) я промолчу). Хелп, ай нид самбади

[image: Ввёл]

[image: Не прибил footer, не бейте]

HTML:

```
`<div class="filter__select filter__select_age">
   <div class="select__title">
      <span>Любой возраст</span>
      <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="select__dropdown">
      <ul class="select__list">
         <li class="active">Любой возраст</li>
         <li>0+</li>
         <li>6+</li>
         <li>12+</li>
         <li>16+</li>
         <li>18+</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
`.select__list li.active {
    background-color: #007aff;
}`
```

jQuery:

```
`$('.filter__select_age li').click(function () {
    $('.filter__select_age li').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.filter__select_age .select__title span').html($(this).html());
});`
```

Решение:

```
const selectAll = $('.filter__select li');
selectAll.click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.filter__select').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    let selectTitle = $(this).text();
    $(this).closest('.filter__select').find('.select__title span').text(selectTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let items = $('.filter__select_age li');
items.on("click", function() {
  items.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  let nameText = $(this).text();  $(this).closest(".filter__select").find(".select__title_text").text(nameText)
});
```

```css
.select__list li.active {
  background-color: #007aff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter__select filter__select_age">
  <div class="select__title">
    <span class="select__title_text">Любой возраст</span>
    <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="select__dropdown">
    <ul class="select__list">
      <li class="active">Любой возраст</li>
      <li>0+</li>
      <li>6+</li>
      <li>12+</li>
      <li>16+</li>
      <li>18+</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно так

Comment: Спасибо! Немного подправил код, чтобы не слетали активные цвета на другиx select__dropdown